# How to use ng-leave-stagger with AngularJS Animate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I'm exploring animation in AngularJS and I've run into a problem getting the staggered CSS animations to work. It works fine when new items are added, but when multiple items are removed at the same time, items are removed from inside the collection rather than from the back. In other words, the items are removed in the opposite order of what I would expect.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="CompaniesCtrl">
  <h2>Companies</h2>
  <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>

  <ul>
      <li class="company" ng-repeat="company in companies">
          <div>
              <h4>{{company.name}}</h4>
              <p>{{company.description}}</p>
          </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function CompaniesCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.companies = [
        { name: "Company A", description: 'A software vendor' },
        { name: "Company B", description: 'Another software vendor' },
        { name: "Company C", description: 'A software consultancy shop' },
        { name: "Company D", description: 'Another software consultancy shop' }
    ];

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.companies.push({ name: "Another company", description: 'Another software consultancy shop' });
        $scope.companies.push({ name: "Another company", description: 'Another software consultancy shop' });
        $scope.companies.push({ name: "Another company", description: 'Another software consultancy shop' });
    };

    $scope.remove = function () {
        $scope.companies.splice($scope.companies.length - 3, 3);
    };
}
```

CSS:

```
.company {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.company.ng-enter-stagger, .company.ng-leave-stagger, .repeat-animation.ng-move-stagger {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
    transition-duration: 0;
}

.company.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s linear all;
    transition:0.2s linear all;

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15)!important;
    transform:scale(1.15)!important;
}
.company.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1)!important;
    transform:scale(1)!important;
}

.company.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.1s linear all;
    transition:0.1s linear all;

    opacity: 1;
}
.company.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle documenting the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/VNB7R/

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong in my JS code or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is how the animate library works. It does not know what has been removed or added it's just re-render the array.

Here is a trick you can apply to mimic the same behaviour using $timeout.

```
    var remove = function () {
        $scope.companies.splice($scope.companies.length - 1, 1);
    };

    $scope.remove = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            $timeout(remove, 100);
    }
```

[Fiddle Modified Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kikoanis/ZaLw7/2/)

Comment: The timeout idea doesn't work that well. One of the cases where the mentioned problem would be evident is when applying an ng-repeat filter. In that case I'm not in charge of showing/hiding items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve it, though it is very much a hack!

I changed the angular.js file (version 1.2.16) by adding the following code at line 20033:

```
var elements = 0;
for (key in lastBlockMap) { if (lastBlockMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) { elements++; } }
for (key in lastBlockMap) { if (lastBlockMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) { forEach(getBlockElements(lastBlockMap[key].clone), function (e) { e.ElementsToRemoveCount = elements; }); } }
```

There might be more elegant ways to write the code but it was written to be as compact as possible and not interfere with the surrounding code.

In addition, the following code must be added to the angular-animate.js file (also version 1.2.16) at line 1227:

```
if (animationEvent == 'leave' && element[0].ElementsToRemoveCount)
   itemIndex = element[0].ElementsToRemoveCount - itemIndex;
```

The first code snippet marks the element with info about the total number of elements to remove. The second code snippet reverses the index used to determine the removeal order in the case of a 'leave' animation.

It is definitely a last resort to hack the angular source files, but I see no alternative. Why it was not implemented to work like this in the first place I don't understand. Also, I have no idea if I have introduced a bunch of bugs or unintended behavior with these changes, but it does appear to work fine.

Comment: which lines are those in https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.js and https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/angular-animate.js ?